# Validate multiple fields inside p:dataList in JSF

Tags: validation, jsf, datalist

I have to validate a name and group field for uniquness for an item. The user can create several items. When the users clicks on a save button I want to check the name and group for all items. In the backing beans the values of the last item are always not set in the validate method. For the last item the values are not set because I am inside the validation at this time. But I do not know how to get the inputtexts name and group for the last item and call getSubmittedValue() because all is inside a dataList and the ids are generated. Any idea?

Cheers
Oliver

Comment: Do you have some code written?

Comment: I solved this my submitting the values via ajax on each change of a field. So I have the values in backing bean when the user presses the save button.